# How to get a general overview of the stack with GDB (or other program)?

Tags: c, gdb, stack, printf

If I have this little C code (that I compile with: `gcc -m32 -o code code.c`):

```
int main(){

    char tab[3];
    tab[0]='a';
    tab[1]='b';
    tab[2]='c';

return 0;
}
```

How can I use GDB (or another program) to get a general overview of the stack like:

```
 ADRESSES      VALUES

 0xbffff260    0x61
 0xbffff261    0x62
 0xbffff262    0x63
```

Thank you

**p.s:** The values should be 0x61, 0x62, 0x63 for a,b,c respectively.

Comment: `print tab` should work..ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html But these are likely to get optimized away, as not doing anything.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to inspect the stack rather than directly dumping the `tab` variable. Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the variables of the local stack try using the gdb command:

```
where
```

If you want the variables of each frame that exists in the program then try using:

```
where full
```

Then if you want to select a specific frame use:

```
frame <frame#>
```

---

### EDIT:

Also, try compiling with -g flag.

```
gcc -g code.c -o code
```

So you can debug in gdb.

Comment: Sorry, but what is a frame please ?

Comment: Each function has different frame. Basically, when you run a function foo() within main(), main for example is the 1st frame and then foo() follows as 2nd frame.
So basically, running "**where full**" gives you the value of the variables of all the functions that are at the stack at the exact moment.